# What is the difference between (boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)::async_read_some and (...)::async_receive?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, tcp

What is the difference between `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_read_some` and `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_receive`?

What is the difference between `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_write_some` and `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::send`?

`async_read_some`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html

`async_receive`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive.html

`async_write_some`:http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html

`async_send`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_send.html